# Как создать таблицу в базе данных средствами php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE 'one' (
           'numer' text NOT NULL,
           'mass' text NOT NULL)
          ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
mysql_query ($query);
```

пробую так, но не получается

Comment: ошибку в студию.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить кавычки ' на `

CREATE TABLE `one` (`numer` text NOT NULL,`mass` text NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: в дополнение к предыдущему комментарию:

        mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE `one` (`numer` text NOT NULL, `mass` text NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");

Comment: и сейчас окажется, что не выбрана бд lol

Comment: бд выбрана, другие запросы норм проходят, ща попробую ковычки заменить

Comment: Напишите, что выведет строка:

    echo mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n";

Answer (score 1):

Вместо одиночных кавычек ' следует использовать обратные кавычки. В MySQL они предназначены для обрамления названия таблиц и столбцов. Таким образом, можно использовать в качестве имен зарезервированные слова, не опасаясь, что анализатор не сможет корректно разобрать SQL-запрос

```
CREATE TABLE `one` (
  `numer` text NOT NULL,
  `mass` text NOT NULL)
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```